# httpRedirect - Redirect from http://www.*.com to http://*.com

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, redirect, web-config

I'm running IIS7 and I need to setup a redirect in my web config - in the httpRedirect...

What I need to do is up a couple permanent redirect:

```
- http://www.*.com to http://*.com, and 
- http://*.com/test.html to http://*.com/test
```

Comment: you have two issues. one is to remove the [www](http://dotnetblogger.com/post/2008/12/03/ASPNET-Force-Website-to-use-WWW.aspx) and one is to [UrlMap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228302.aspx)

Comment: Isn't there a way to **remove** the www from the config?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rule for IIS7 that will work for your first requirement.  The RedirectType is permanent (301).

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^www\.(\w+\.com)$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Your second requirement will require the following rules:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^domain\.com/test\.html$" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" negate="true" pattern="^POST$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="domain.com/test" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^domain\.com/test$" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="domain.com/test.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

These rules will rewrite `http://domain.com/test.html` to `http://domain.com/test`.
You may need to change some of the settings to fit your needs.

Comment: With the second rewrite... why are there 2 rules?

Comment: Good question.  The first rule will redirect the user to `domain.com/test` if the url is `domain.com/test.html`, but if the incoming URL is `domain.com/test`, then it will keep that as the URL, but redirect the user to the page test.html.  This is asuming that you have such a page and a need to do that. If you have no need for this rule, then you can leave it out.